# History push state redirects instead of just pushing new state to browser history

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular-routing, browser-history

I am trying to push a new state to browser history on my APP initialization but while pushing the state it also redirects the page which is not required.

Here is a demo working app.
https://angular-tet5fy.stackblitz.io/page2?fbclid=IwAR1zP_UTnCQxKMp8o3ZXf-n4NR3ftu_4JoulLqItaONa-_wSPJ_DT95OgRU

This is the code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('init called');
    var x = document.referrer;
    console.log('ref', x);

    if (x) {
      console.log('pushing state');
      this.location.pushState({id:'page3'}, 'Page3', '/page3');
    }
}
```

Expected behavior:

1. Clicking on the link takes the user to page2.
2. While page2 is initialized it should push state '/page3' to the browser history.
3. When the user clicks the browser back now it should take to /page3 as it is was pushed to history in step2 above.

Current Behaviour:

1. Clicking on the link, takes me to page2 but it automatically redirects to /page3 while pushing state.
2. When clicked browser back, it takes me back to /page2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('init called');
    var x = document.referrer;
    console.log('ref', x);

    if (x) {
      console.log('pushing state');
      let locat = location.href;
      history.replaceState({id:'page3'},'Page3','/page3');
      history.pushState(null,null,locat);
    }
}
```

What we do here it's change the url to the url *you want to be the back* with `history.replaceState({id:'page3'},'Page3','/page3');` and then make a new entry in the history with  `history.pushState(null, null,locat);` witht he first url.

I answered you this question already in two different posts with only a little variation:

[Angular platformLocation pushState not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494629/angular-platformlocation-pushstate-not-working)

[Angular: take user to home on clicking browser back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55491448/angular-take-user-to-home-on-clicking-browser-back-button)

**Live example fork:**
https://angular-stack-55624908.stackblitz.io/page2

Comment: Yes you answered but you were checking if state is null then redirect through router service. But this looks a workaround and not a proper solution as browser should itself take care of navigation when we are pushing the state using history.pushState

Comment: Also I am glad that you previous solution did work and hence I voted it up but this problem statement is a small part of a bigger problem statement hence I am looking for browser history to take care if the navigations.

Comment: Did you see the solution? It covers the problem. I don't see what's the problem now exactly. Can you explain it a little more deep? because with that code It should work.
In another note, you didn't upvote it or mark it as the correct answer in any of the other two posts.

Answer (score 1):

> Expected behavior:
>   1. Clicking on the link takes the user to page2.
>   2. While page2 is initialized it should push state '/page3' to the browser history.
>   3. When the user clicks the browser back now it should take to /page3 as it is was pushed to history in step2 above.

Because what you did, your history state goes: p1 -> p2 -> p3. That's in your description! You want it like this:

1. Clicking on the link first push state p3
2. Then take user to p2, and don't push state when initialized
3. Browser back now works as expected

---

Edit:

This is how you can implement it. In `page2.component.ts`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  history.replaceState({ data: 'at page 3' }, 'Page3', '/page3');
  history.pushState({ data: 'at page 2' }, 'Page2', '/page2');
}
```

But again, read the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Comment: Yes, you got me right. I want to push a state '/page3' before user lands to page2 so when the user clicks back he is taken to page3.

Comment: @VarunSukheja Ah, so you know the correct steps like I proposed, but you don't know how to implement them, right?

Comment: @VarunSukheja read this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) thoroughly first, give feedback on what you have tried.

Comment: check the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wb9fnf?file=src/app/app.component.ts. I am just pushing a url while my app is initializing but it redrects to page3. To see the code in action click https://angular-wb9fnf.stackblitz.io/page2